# Difference between WNetAddConnection2() and NetUseAdd()

Tags: c++, windows, user-accounts, mount-point

I'm mounting a remote drive locally (see [User/password problems with GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint() (Windows remote drive mount?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447315/user-password-problems-with-getvolumenameforvolumemountpoint-windows-remote-dr))

**QUESTION:  What is the difference between `WNetAddConnection2()` and `NetUseAdd()`?**  It appears they each permit you to assign a remote drive path to a local drive letter providing username and password.

Further, I can call `WNetAddConnection2()` specifying a local drive letter (works), or specifying "NULL" for the local drive letter, and the console `net use` command will show success mounting the remote drive to "nothing" locally -- as you would expect -- but I'm unsure of the purpose for that kind of result.  My hope was that it would establish "logon credentials" between the local system/process and the remote computer so that other calls to `::GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint()` would have correct username/password context, but that doesn't work for me.

The ultimate goal is to mount the remote drive locally *without* a local drive letter (to something like a local GUID path share because all 26 local drive letters are already in use), but all calls to `::GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint()` fail with `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password`, even after I successfully mount remotely to a local drive letter providing the remote username and password (currently using `WNetAddConnection2()`).

Comment: NetUseAdd-
You could just pass null as the local drive letter, no local drive will 
be mapped and you can use unc path format to access the remote resource.

Comment: @weeyoung, that's no difference, works on both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NetUseAdd()` makes the connection visible in Windows Explorer, while `WNetUseConnection()` and `WNetAddConnection()` do not make the connection visible in Windows Explorer.

Comment: FYI, today I confirmed that the drive letters mounted with `WNetUseConnection2()` *are* visible through Windows Explorer (on Windows Vista).  Weird.

Comment: Unaccepted and confirmed, they both expose in Windows Explorer which is absolutely not what I want, if anyone would happen to have a solution to that, I would be happy to hear about it ;o)

Comment: @charley Where is there documentation for `WNetUseConnection2`? (Or did you mean `WNetAddConnection2`?)